# live Streaming audio delays while playing in android-16?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I am developing a small android application in which i am playing the rtsp link using android media player .It is working properly on less then android 16 api. but the problem is that when i run on android 16 it take lots of time to play and some time it even does not play.following is the code which I am using

```
sdrPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
sdrPlayer.setDataSource(url);
sdrPlayer.prepare();
sdrPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(video.this);
sdrPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(video.this);
sdrPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(video.this);
sdrPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Following are some test case

1. ZTE N860 – Takes about 4 to 5 mins to start playing the Radio.
2. Samsung Galaxy S4 – Audio doesn’t work at all. It call start method
   in `onprepare` method but there is no audio.
3. Samsung SCH1415 - Takes about 8 mins to start playing the Radio
4. HTC V5 – Audio doesn’t work all the time. It starts playing but
   there is no audio. The behavior is inconsistent and that’s causing
   more frustration.

Comment: Nitin, I would suggest that you sniff the traffic to the server if you can and compare the 2 RTSP exchanges. I recall reading somewhere that the RTSP implementation update on some Android version broke many existing applications. If that is the case, you should see some difference in the RTSP exchange.

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment @Ralf but android 16 always take time to load the link first time when we load link and on some occasion randomly.Also the media player's is playing method gives true.so i can not show progress. but some times it works correctly.Is it possible that server always send some corrupted bits at first and some times.

Comment: The wait times are caused by the audio buffer size. I believe the size was increased with Android 16+. What is your question? Since you can't control the buffer size you are out of luck if you want to use MediaPlayer. My application uses a FFmpeg based player so I can control the buffer size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for playing rtsp link you should use `sdrPlayer.prepareAsync();` instead of

```
sdrPlayer.prepare();
```

because the documentation says

It prepares the player for playback, asynchronously. After setting the datasource and the display surface, you need to either call `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()`. **For streams, you should call `prepareAsync()`**, which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered.